# Android callback when trying to make a screenshot in my app

Tags: android, screenshot, video-player, drm

I have an `Android` application with a video player with `DRM`. When I try to take a screenshot after the video player in my app is opened I see the message: `"Can't take screenshot due to security policy"`. It is okay, but I want to customize this message or, in the best way, have a callback when the user tries to make a screenshot (for example, show him
an alert dialog with my message).

How can I make it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312725/3022836

Answer (score 1):

As this message came from OS, unfortunately you can not edit it. Also you can not have an event which triggers after this toast.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://github.com/rbague/ScreenshotCallback)

> OR

1. Gradle dependency Add it in your project-level build.gradle at the end of repositories:

   allprojects {
   repositories {
   ...
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
   }

Add the dependency in yout app-level build.gradle:

```
implementation'com.github.rbague:ScreenshotCallback:v1.0'
```

**Usage**

Add this permission to `AndroidManifest.xml` and remeber to request it:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Example of listening for screenshots while an activity is being shown:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ScreenshotObserver mObserver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        mObserver = new ScreenshotObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onScreenshotTaken(String path) {
                //Your code here
            }
        };
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mObserver != null) {
            //Must be called or mObserver won't receive any calls
            mObserver.startListnening(); 
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mObserver != null) {
            mObserver.stopListening();
        }
    }
}
```